# Why is there a difference between resolve("./../....") and resolve("foo")

Tags: node.js, typescript

Due to different node versions and different ABI incompatibilities I need to load a C++ addon relatively because they are located with different ABI versions at different locations.

But the issue I am having is even simpler explained. Why do the 2 following calls differ?

```
const nodegit = require("./../path/to/nodegit.node");
const nodegit = require("nodegit");
```

Afaik both calls load the same library. But there is a difference. As an example I want to use [Repository.init](https://www.nodegit.org/api/repository/#init) which has the following function header:

```
Repository.init(repo_path, 0).then(function(repository) {
  // Use repository
});
```

If I call this now with:

```
nodegit.Repository.init("/path/to/randm/dir", 0);
```

I get this exception:

```
Callback is required and must be a Function.
```

It seems to be that the returned Promise became an argument of the init function. Am I missing something or does `require` interpret this library in a different manner if its relative?

Comment: Why do you need to use the relative path?

Comment: Because I have different ABI versions and different node versions for my project

Comment: Something else must be going on. You think you are getting the same library, but maybe you aren't.

Comment: I thought so as well but I used Xcode Instruments and on Windows Process Monitor to verify the same `nodegit.node` file is loaded. And the require call also succeeds, but the call to Repository.init fails and is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calls differ because the `require('nodegit')` entrypoint wraps `require("./../path/to/nodegit.node")` and provides a better JavaScript experience. You can see it here: https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/master/generate/templates/templates/nodegit.js#L11-L23. It was much easier to write the API in JavaScript than C++, which is ultimately why it works this way. You can still use the native binary directly, but you'll get an experience closer to libgit2 without the NodeGit API.

Answer (score 1):

- "nodegit" is the package main entry point
- "./../path/to/nodegit.node" the native extension alone

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot! So I can move the entire C++ extension alone to another directory and load this instead?